# Lumen - Create migrations in mysql but default mongodb connection

Tags: mysql, mongodb, connection, lumen

In my lumen application, I am using mongodb (default connection) and mysql connection. I have added both connections in .env file and config/database.php file.

So far I have been using mongodb and now I want to create some tables in mysql using migration. I created migration. (Migration file is created but not table). In migration file, I have specified connection as "mysql" and also schema definition as follows:

```
protected $connection = 'mysql';

public function up()
    {
        Schema::connection('mysql')->create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique;
            $table->string('password');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

However, when I hit command php artisan migrate, I am getting following error
**$collectionName is invalid**

Can you help me so that I can create tables in mysql by keeping mongodb as default connection?

Answer (score 0):

That's weird, that one should work.
Is there by any chance some class included in that migration that shouldn't be in there? Happened to me a couple of times that I added per mistake some wrong class into a `use`.

And a couple of alternative approaches:

The easiest way would be to just specify the different connection when running the migration itself.
You can pass it as option in the command directly:
`php artisan migrate --database=mysql` 
Of course that means that you shouldn't have multiple migrations for different databases within that one batch.

And if that's not possible then a way around would be to set the default connection before the table creation part..

```
\DB::setDefaultConnection('mysql');

 Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
etc... 

// !!!!switch it back to mongodb afterwards if the batch includes migrations for multiple connections
\DB::setDefaultConnection('mongodb');
```

Comment: php artisan migrate --database=mysql worked.
However, now new issue is following message

SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.  (SQL: select * from information_sch
  ema.tables where table_schema = my_table and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.

Basically, I am using docker compose to build services (application, sqldb for mysql, nosqldb for mongo)and in my env file, I have mentioned service name 'sqldb' as DB_HOST

Comment: Can you connect to that database from anywhere else @Barbara?
You can quickly verify whether it's something wrong with the database/config itself by trying to connect through the command line directly, with the same credentials and see if that is able to connect or not.

`mysql --host=host_name --user=usr --password=psw db_name`

If it gives you an error then there is something wrong with the credentials or the db itself.